# How to active only one button at a time in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have group of four buttons

```
 <button round ion-button> David </button>

 <button round ion-button> Rocky</button>

 <button round ion-button> Chris</button>

 <button round ion-button> Johny</button>
```

I want to make the button active (change background color) only one button at a time in typescript. How to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NgClass` directive to conditionally assign the CSS class to your active button. To achieve this you'll need the CSS class and a property in your .ts to know what's the active button.

So your .TS will be:

```
export class YourPage {
  public active: string; // add this property
  constructor() { }

  // method to update the active property
  updateActive = name => this.active = name;
}
```

And then change your HTML:

```
<button round ion-button [ngClass]="'your-css-class': active === 'david'" (click)="updateActive('david')"> David </button>

<button round ion-button [ngClass]="'your-css-class': active === 'rocky'" (click)="updateActive('rocky')"> Rocky</button>

<button round ion-button [ngClass]="'your-css-class': active === 'chris'" (click)="updateActive('chris')"> Chris</button>

<button round ion-button [ngClass]="'your-css-class': active === 'johny'" (click)="updateActive('johny')"> Johny</button>
```

This should work, if you need a button to start active just asign a value to it in your `active` property. If your active button'll be managed in your .ts file just remove the click attribute. Here's the [NgClass docs page](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) if you need furter assistance.

Hope this helps.

### UPDATE

Updated to use a method instead of directly assigning the value on the click, as op asked for.

Comment: How to write the function in Typescript for this ?

Comment: @Abdulkhader updated my answer so it can use a method instead of directly assigning the value on click.